# Python For-Loop over specific dates

Tags: python, for-loop, timestamp

my question is about a simple `For` loop. I have a CSV file with an hourly performance over 4 years. The problem is that I need an average output per month.  Therefore I use the sum of all outputs per month divided by the amount of outputs. My input file has the following format:

```
                      power_output
timestamp                        
2012-01-01 00:00:00   2335.215265
2012-01-01 01:00:00   3097.521354
2012-01-01 02:00:00   3412.639293
2012-01-01 03:00:00   3366.400549
2012-01-01 04:00:00   3431.050170
```

The form of the timestamp is yyyy-mm-dd and than the hour.

My problem is now, that I'm not able to iterate with the `for` -loop over the timestamp for one month. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have to use a loop and do this by hand? Or can you use a library like pandas?

Comment: @datasailor I can use libraries.  I open the csv file also with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your data as a timeseries in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=True)
```

Now you can simply [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) your data, e.g.

```
df.resample('1M').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set up a 2D array with one list for each month.

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='   ')
    year_outages = [ [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] ]
    for row in reader:
        month = row[0][5:7]
        year_outages[int(month)].append(float(row[1]))
```

Then to calculate average for the month of February for example, you do:

```
feb_avg = sum(year_outages[1])/len(year_outages[1])
```